# Login - > First View (tableviewcontroller)

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, authentication

I'm having a bit of a problem getting my head round the logic. At the moment, I have a login and the main app. Upon a successful login, the user can access the main up. However, on the first view after the login, there are 4 cells on the tableviewcontroller. This changes depending on the user. So a user may have access to only 3 of the 4 cells.

I have implemented Json further down in my app so I kind of understand how it works. My question is, upon Login, how can I send something so that my app can read for it to show a certain number of cells?

P.S. at the moment, I thinking of when User 1 logs in, it will echo 1110 (3 of the 4 cells appear) and when User 2 logs in, it will echo 1111 (all cells appear). But how would my "First View" page read this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/), or if you prefer an alternative, very good framework with lots of added benefits, check [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

By using either of this class you are able to ask your server for any data you need so that you can show it in your `UITableView` (by creating an appropriate data source from the data).

Comment: Can I not do something where I could possibly #import my login page to my 1st view? So in the viewDidLoad, I could read what the login page 'echo' and then build the cells according to that?

Comment: Sorry K.Honda, but it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What kind of data are you handling? Where do they come from? What do you mean by "echo"ing? Maybe you should try to give us some fuller idea about your application...

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what I've asked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109543/how-to-make-one-page-pass-on-a-message-to-another Does this make things clearer for you?

Comment: @K.Honda: sorry, it is still not clear... what I understand is: 1) the user connect to some server through your app; 2) if login is ok, the server replies back with some content (XML? HTML? JSON?); 3) now, you would like that your app shows a new view with a table containing the data that the server sent back. Is this right?