# How to make one page pass on a message to another?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, authentication, viewdidload

My problem is different users will have access to different products. Say User 1 has access to 3 whereas User 2 has access to all 4.

Can I have something upon Login where if User 1 logs in, it will tell the MainView to only show 3 cells? Something like ViewDidLoad in the MainView to read what the Login Page echo-ed?

Can that be done?

Thanks.

Comment: @Abizem: Please can you assist me on how to store a global variable? I am quite new to objective-c and so it would be great if you could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a global variable in **appdelegate** like **numberOfCells**.
Assign value to it by the condition of your login.

Once your MainView is about to display like in viewWillAppear, get the value of **numberOfCells** from **appdelegate** and chage your UI.

You can get the appdelegate reference as follows.

```
SampleAppDelegate *appdelegate=(SampleAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Hello, could you please assist me in doing this as I am unfamiliar with this. Thanks.

Comment: @Honda: take a variable as int numberOfCells in appdelegate. when you, login update the value of numberOfCells variable based on the user who logged in, then u can get that value when your view is displayed

Comment: Can you possibly give me a walkthrough on this? Like what to put in appDelegate.h and .m etc. as I'm not sure where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the user who has 'logged-it' you can configure your views based on that user/profile.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `NSUserDefaults`??

You can save alot of field in it and will be accessible throughout your project.